# load a 200MB xlsx file in vue

Tags: google-chrome, stream, out-of-memory, xlsx, chunks

I want to load large xlsx data (200MB) in Vue.

- Browser used: chrome
- When reading large data with XLSX.read() as follows, the browser crashes with error: out of memory (currently crashes even at 20MB)

```
<template>
<el-upload
class="upload-demo"
ref="upload"
action="/"
accept=".xls,.xlsx"
:file-list="fileList"
:multiple="false"
:on-change="onSelectLocalFile"
:show-file-list="true"
:on-remove="removeList"
:auto-upload="false"
>
<el-button size="mini">{{ "ファイルを選択" }}</el-button>
</el-upload>
</template>

<script>

import XLSX from "xlsx";
async readLocalFile() {
 this.srcFlg = "0";
 this.sheetName = "";
 return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        const _this = this;
        reader.onload = async function (e) {
          const data = e.target.result;
          console.log('data :', data)
          _this.workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: "binary" });
          await _this.readWorkBook();
          resolve();
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(file.raw);
      });
    },

</script>
```

Is it possible to load large xlsx data in the browser?
I've tried separating it into streaming and chunk but I'm not sure.

Comment: You can use the `XLSX Streaming API` to load large XLSX files